# Extracting and renaming jpeg files from an xlsx file

Tags: python

I have written this piece of code to extract jpeg pictures from an xlsx file and then copy and rename them multiple times. It works but it doesn't allow me to save the renamed pictures into another folder inside the C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop\\XLSpix directory, where code and xlsx file are located. What happens is the first extracted picture gets saved into a new \\xl\\media folder inside the above mentioned directory and i get an  'Impossible to find the specified path' Error. If I don't add the \\pictures folder it will save the renamed pictures outside of the \\xl\\media folder.
Here is the code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import re
import os
import time
dest_dir= 'C:\\Users\\divel\\Desktop\\XLSpix' #I add \\pictures here
file_name= "fote.xlsx"

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zipObj:
     lista = list(zip(file_name))
     counter = 0
     
     for file in zipObj.infolist():
         name = ''.join(list(file.filename))
         print(name)
         match = re.findall("jpeg$", name)
         if match:
             
             for i in range(3):
                 os.path.join(dest_dir, name)
                 zipObj.extract(file, dest_dir)
                 new_name = 'newPic'+str(counter)+str(i)+'.jpeg'
                 os.rename(name, new_name)
             counter += 1
```

Sorry if my explanation isn't very clear, I am still new to coding and quite confused.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at an "unzip -l" of your Excel files?  Here's a sample from one of mine:

```
     1026  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image7.png
     1114  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image6.png
      790  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image5.png
      433  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image4.png
      510  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image3.png
      230  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image2.png
   894744  03-23-2020 06:11   xl/media/image1.jpeg
```

The image files are all organized into subdirectories.  If you just want the file names, use `os.path.basename(name)`.

Comment: Thank you. Getting the name of the files wasn't actually my main concern. I was just wondering if it is possible to extract a picture without those two additional folders being created around it.

Comment: Of course it is.  YOU are creating those folders, because you are copying the whole path.  If you remove that part of the path, then the folders won't be created.  All you have to do is strip the folder prefix from the filename in the zip before you write the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite an eye-opener. I'll try to figure out a way of doing it.